# Xamarin iOS GPS error

Tags: ios, xamarin, gps

I recently updated to the last version of Xamarin for iOS and know I have this problem where the permission for the gps to obtain the location just turns off when you enter the app.

Anyone having the same problem? I have investigated and it seems to be happening in iOS 8.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS 8 you need to invoke `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` or `requestAlwaysAuthorization`. Follow this guide for starters: http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/content_controls/map_view/display_device_location/

Also, you can remove your app from the device/simulator and on the next deploy it should ask for the location permission again.

A common pitfall is to not have the *Info.plist* key/value set for `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` or `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`.